# Twig global variable into symfony controller

Tags: symfony, twig, global-variables, symfony4

In my Symfony 4 application I use a Twig global variable to store the name of my website. I need to fetch its value both into my templates and controllers.

```
twig:
    globals:
        site_title: My blog
```

I am able to get it inside my Twig templates : `{{ site_title }}`

In my controller, I tried `$this->getParameter('site_title')` but :

> The parameter "site_title" must be defined.

Comment: Read [How to Inject Variables into all Templates (i.e. global Variables)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$twigglobals = $this->get("twig")->getGlobals();
```

and you can get content by:

```
 $site_title = $twigglobals["site_title"];
```